# Auto index complicated formulas with catcode

Tags: catcodes, imakeidx

**original post**

Below is the minimally working code for a program that I am working on. My problem is that when I used more complicated code, it doesn't index automatically at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{imakeidx} %allows for multiple indexes
\usepackage{xcolor}

\catcode`"=\active
\def"#1" {\textcolor{white}{#1}} %catcode to color words white, as to hide it on the the compile format

\catcode`@=\active
\def@[#1][#2][#3]@ {#2\index[#1]{$\square$ "#3" #2}}  %catcode for FORMULAS that are sent to specific indexes as needed, here I use the catcode for "" in order to hide the letter that will allow for the index to be rearranged. so #3 will denote the order of the index, however it will be invisible to the naked eye on white paper so that the formula indexes are easier to read

%making indexes as needed
%  \makeindex[name=NICKNAME, title={INDEX_TITLE},columns=1, intoc]

\makeindex[name=PV, title={Present Value},columns=1, intoc]

\usepackage{lipsum} %creating filler text for demonstration/test purposes

\begin{document}

@[PV][$PV$=summation $\frac{C}{(1+r)^n}$][c]@
\index[PV]{$\square  PV = \sum \frac{C}{(1+r)^n}$}

@[PV][$PV = \sum \frac{C}{(1+r)^n}$][b]@


\indexprologue{Present Value is the discounted value, is the value of an expected income stream determined as of the date of valuation}
\printindex[PV]  

\end{document}
```

When I do the normal input for adding something into an index, the complicated formula does show up somewhat in a similar form. This is still not ideal. Is there a way to better define the \catcode so that I can input more complicated formulas into the index?

**UPDATED code**

Following is updated code based on @barbara beeton info

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{imakeidx} %allows for multiple indexes
%\usepackage{xcolor} no longer needed

%\catcode`"=\active
%\def"#1" {\textcolor{blue}{#1}}  no longer need this as redefined the following catcode

\catcode`"=\active %changed symbol as @ is a seperator in makeidx
\def"[#1][#2][#3]" {#2\index[#1]{#3@$\square$ #2}}  %catcode for FORMULAS that are sent to specific indexes as needed, #3 is used to take advantage of the fact that indexes are alphabetical to order the formulas in an organized manor. Ultimately this /catcode is used to print the #2 in the main text AND index #2 into the appropriate index, #1. 


%making indexes as needed
%  \makeindex[name=NICKNAME, title={INDEX_TITLE},columns=1, intoc]
\makeindex[name=PV, title={Present Value},columns=1, intoc]

\usepackage{lipsum} %creating filler text for demonstration/test purposes

\begin{document}

"[PV][$PV$= summation $\frac{C}{(1+r)^n}$][c]" %appears in index and maintext
\lipsum[2]
"[PV][$PV=\frac{C}{(1+r)^n}$][a]" %appears in index and main text

"[PV][$PV=\sum\frac{C}{(1+r)^n}$][b]" %appears in maintext BUT NOT IN INDEX


%this is what i want to appear in the index using the catcode
%\index[PV]{$\square PV=\sum\frac{C}{(1+r)^n}$}


\indexprologue{Present Value is the discounted value, is the value of an expected income stream determined as of the date of valuation}
\printindex[PV]  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  My memory may be faulty, but I believe the syntax of the `\index` entry is incorrect -- you need a "sort field" for the entry to be placed in the "correct" location (presumably under "PV" or some explicit word indicating "square"), and that depends on the presence of `@` as a separator between the sort field and the expansion.  That is made impossible since you have re-catcoded `@`.  Look at the beginning of your index; the entry is probably sorted where `$` would be sorted.

Comment: I am a little new to latex, so I didn't entirely understand the second part of your comment, but I will clarify a few things. The way i understand the parameters for \index in makeidx are \index[index name]{content}. the \square is only to create a small square bullet before the content because im using indexes to make a formula sheet. Since this will be a long formula page and I want the formulas to appear in a certain order, I use the fact that indexes are alphabetical. I use a dummy letter between the square bullet and the formula which would order the formulas.

Comment: Here's an example of an index entry with a math expression, copied from the makeindex documentation: `\index{alpha@$\alpha$}`. This will appear in the index as the Greek letter alpha, sorted under the "a"s in alphabetical order where the spelled-out word "alpha" would appear. The string "alpha" before the `@` is what is used for the sort; what's after the `@` is what is printed in the index. Your re-catcoding of `@` means this wouldn't work properly. The makeindex sort is just ascii, hence the `$` in your index entry will be the beginning of the sort field, followed by literal `\square`.

Comment: Since all your index entries are actually formulas, and will have the same input format, this may be okay.  Be careful to make the spacing identical in all entries -- multiple spaces are *not* treated as single spaces in the makeindex sort.

Comment: I have updated my code and edited my original post to reflect this. Using the @ function in makeidx is a much better way of doing what I had orginally done, so I changed the symbol in my /catcode and remove the some extra code and functions that are no longer needed. I also removed all the spacing in my formulas, however I still am having trouble getting the formula to appear in the index with \sum. It only appears in the main body of my document.

Comment: From your comment, I infer that you end up with an index containing two entries, missing only the one with `\sum`.  If so, there should be a log file from makeindex containing one error message.  If there's not a specially named index, the extension of the log file would be `.ilg`; even if it's not, you should be able to find it.  Also, there should be an input file for makeindex; again, the extension would be something like the default, `.idx'.  What does the entry look like that isn't processed?

Comment: Correct, three formulas in the main doc appearing correctly, and only two formulas in the index. the missing entry just doesn't appear, wouldve never known any different if i wasn't paying attention to it. I can't read my .idx file but I found the `.ilg` file and this is what it says. "!! Input index error (file = PV.idx, line = 3):
   -- Extra `@' at position 29 of first argument.
done (2 entries accepted, 1 rejected)."  Looking at the /catcode definition and #2 in the missing formula, i am unable to identify the where the extra @ could be.

Comment: What I would do is create a new test directory and put just the test file in it.  Then I would run the job and look to see what files were created; one of them must be the "logical" `.idx` file.  Another possibility is to use the `[original]` option for `imakeidx` -- that will stop the run before running makeindex -- and then run makeindex manually from the command line.  That way it will be clear exactly which file is which.  It's necessary to know what the entry looks like in the `.idx` file.

Comment: Ah, this worked and i can now read my `.idx` file. I included the \index form of the formula in this test file, so that i can compare where the missing formula is read differently. this is what the `.idx` file says. 
"\indexentry{b@$\square $ $PV=\DOTSB \sum@ \slimits@ \frac  {C}{(1+r)^n}$}{1}
\indexentry{$\square PV=\sum\frac{C}{(1+r)^n}$}{1}" I can see that there are 2 extra @ signs in the way that the catcode version is read. I've tried googling around to see how i could redefine or fix the way the \sum is read in the catcode. would that be a possible approach to this?

Comment: I don't understand why `\sum` is transformed to `\sum@`, but entering `\protect\sum` may prevent that.  (At the moment, I don't have access to a working tex system, so this is all from extensive past experience; in other words, "educated hacking".)

Comment: That worked PERFECTLY!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from the comments, @barbara beeton was able to find the problem. I am posting an answer for others to be able to find and solve.

- *Syntax error in original code*: `@` is already a separator in `\makeidx` so redefining that in the `\catcode` caused problems and a more complex code than needed. *Solution:* use " as the catcode symbol

After this, the file would compile without any errors however there would still be formula missing in the index.

**SOLUTION**

1. First to understand what is being interpreted in the indexes log files. `.ilg` file will tell you if there are any errors and if there is anything being ignored in the process of compiling the index. *If there is any error or that any entries are rejected or ignored. go to the next step*.
2. `.idx` will show exactly is being read into the index. so open this into any text file reader like Notepad. This will show you how your input is being translated and read into the index which can help you pinpoint the problematic portion. In my case `\sum` was being read as `\DOTSB \sum@ \slimits@`. *If your command is being transformed into something funky then continue to last step*
3. `\protect` will prevent the command from being transformed into something else. So in this case, '$\sum\frac$ is now '\protect\sum \frac' and now the complex formula appears in the index as it should without any errors. this can be confirmed by looking at the `.idx` and `.ilg`files as well.

**FINAL CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{imakeidx} %allows for multiple indexes


\catcode`"=\active 
\def"[#1][#2][#3]" {#2\index[#1]{#3@$\square$ #2}}  %catcode for FORMULAS that are sent to specific indexes (defined by #1) as needed. #3 is used to take advantage of the fact that indexes are alphabetical to order the formulas in an organized manor. Ultimately this /catcode is used to automatically print the #2 in the main text AND index #2 into the appropriate index at the same time 


%making indexes as needed
%  \makeindex[name=NICKNAME, title={INDEX_TITLE},columns=1, intoc]
\makeindex[name=PV, title={Present Value},columns=1, intoc]


\begin{document}


%"[PV][$PV=\sum \frac{C}{(1+r)^n}$][b]" %appeared in maintext BUT NOT IN INDEX

"[PV][$PV=\protect\sum \frac{C}{(1+r)^n}$][b]" %appears in both index and main text


\indexprologue{Present Value is the discounted value, is the value of an expected income stream determined as of the date of valuation}
\printindex[PV]  

\end{document}
```

Comment: According to the package documentation, "The `quote` operator is used to escape symbols", so making it active could cause problems, although not likely in this particular application.  (For example, if a literal `!` should appear in the output, it can be entered as `"!`.)  I rather liked the choice of the "euro" in the original updated code in your question, since that doesn't have any assigned function that I'm aware of.)

Comment: The € wasn't recognized as a character and nothing compiled. I liked it as well. Is there a compiled list of usually acceptable characters that can be used?

Comment: I can't think of a formal list of characters, but will try to find one, or think of a possible "free" one.  On the other hand, now that you've got a nice reliable 3-argument situation, maybe an ordinary control sequence, for example `\Vindex`, would suffice.